# Remove axis labels in R conditional density plot

Tags: r, label

I could not manage to remove the y axis labels from a conditional density plot (cdplot{graphics}) in order to rotate them horizontally later; `axes = FALSE` seems not to work. Any idea?
**Thanks!**

Using the example data from R documentation:

```
fail <- factor(c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
               levels = 1:2, labels = c("no", "yes"))
temperature <- c(53, 57, 58, 63, 66, 67, 67, 67, 68, 69, 70, 70, 70, 70, 72, 73, 75, 75, 76, 76, 78, 79, 81)
cdplot(fail ~ temperature, axes = FALSE)

Warning messages:
1: In density.default(x, bw = bw, n = n, ...) :
  non-matched further arguments are disregarded
2: In density.default(x[y %in% levels(y)[seq_len(i)]], bw = dx$bw,  :
  non-matched further arguments are disregarded
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you pose your question with some minimal reproducible code and sample data.  See this question for help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/602276

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are not giving us any data, I'm using the data provided in `example(spineplot)`.

You can get rid of the axis labels by setting the appropriate parameter to `NA`:

```
spineplot(fail~temperature,yaxlabels=NA)
```

But if you want to orient them horizontally, you normally set `las=1`. Unfortunately, `spineplot` doesn't seem to pass this on, so you need to do a call to `par` first:

```
par(las=1)
spineplot(fail~temperature)
```